# How to push elements to react hooks state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap-table

I am using `react-bootstrap-table2` to make HTML tables, I am using a checkbox inside my table to delete the items.

SO as per [This link](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/row-select-props.html#selectrowclicktoselect-bool), it is mentioned how to get the selected row and then do the next part, here what I am doing is when I click on any checkbox row gets selected, and if I again select any row that I am adding to the array into my state like below

```
onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex, e) => {
        if (isSelect === true) {
            setrowData((rowData) => [...rowData, row]);
        } else {
        //  here i need to do something
        }
    },
```

My issue is when I unselect the row that value is not getting deleted from my array, and at the time of delete, I have all the data which I have selected once.

- One more thing which is related to this is when I check any row I want to show delete button and when none of the rows is checked I want to hide the delete button, here `select` is giving me the boolean value for that, but it is working for each select once I am selecting multiple rows it shows up, but when I unselect any one of them the delete button hides

**What I have done for that is something like below**

```
setrowSelect((rowSelect) => [...rowSelect, isSelect]); // this one is inside onSelect callback given by the react-bootstrap-table2 library

           {rowSelect && (
                    <button className="btn Secondary_Button_with_Icon">
                        <i className="ri-upload-cloud-line ri-lg"></i>Register
                    </button>
                )}
```

[My full working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-dream-sqywq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Did my solution help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, you don't need to maintain another state for controlling visibility of `Delete` button.

> You can perfectly hide/show Delete based on `rowData` state.

Also the code you wrote for handling selected rows works perfectly well. Just get rid of `rowSelect` state and its handlers.

And update the rendering of your `Delete` button based on contents of your `rowData` as:

```js
{
    rowData.length ? (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={Delete_device}>
          <i className="ri-upload-cloud-line ri-lg"></i>Delete
        </button>
      )
    : null
}
```

This is the [forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-cloud-xcrk3) from yours.

Answer (score 2):

Use a filter method inside your else block to remove that unselected element from the array

```
 onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex, e) => {
      if (isSelect === true) {
        setrowData((rowData) => [...rowData, row]);
      } else {
        setrowData((rowData) => rowData.filter((x,i)=>i!==rowIndex))
      }
      setrowSelect((rowSelect) => [...rowSelect, isSelect]);
    },
```

Comment: hey that isSelect still the same, when I select rows button is showing up, but when I uncheck all the rows still button is there

Answer (score 1):

try to change onSelect function like this

```
  onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex, e) => {
  if (isSelect === true) {
    setrowData((rowData) => [...rowData, row]);
    rowSelect.push(true);
    setrowSelect(rowSelect);
  } else {
    setrowData((rowData) => rowData.filter((x, i) => i !== rowIndex));     
      rowSelect.pop();
      setrowSelect(rowSelect);
  }
}
```

Comment: no it is not working, when i select two rows buttons shows up, but when i un select one button again set to hidden please check code sandbox

Comment: I have updated sandbox.now Its working
  onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex, e) => {
      if (isSelect === true) {
        setrowData((rowData) => [...rowData, row]);
        rowSelect.push(true);
        setrowSelect(rowSelect);
      } else {
        setrowData((rowData) => rowData.filter((x, i) => i !== rowIndex));     
          rowSelect.pop();
          setrowSelect(rowSelect);
      }
    }

Comment: where is your code sandbox ? I have tried your edited answer it is not working, as expected.

Comment: but there it is not updating, please create your own and share me the link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-diffie-midxt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hey don't you thing on `onSelectAll` you are passing `setrowSelect([true, true, true]);` because there are 3 rows, but here in this case rows are dynamic, what you doing is hack around

Comment: you can easily make it dynamic using map loop

Comment: hey I tried  `rows.map((li) => {
     setrowSelect([true]);
     console.log(li);
    });` but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to implement what you want :

1.Keep your data in one object, and add an **id** and **isSelect** fields

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "id-1",
    fname: "john",
    lname: "smith",
    isSelect: false
  },
  {
    id: "id-2",
    fname: "steve",
    lname: "warn",
    isSelect: false
  },
  {
    id: "id-3",
    fname: "michel",
    lname: "clark",
    isSelect: false
  }
];
```

2.pass this data to `useState` :

```
const [rowData, setrowData] = useState(data);
```

3.`onSelect` : just find the row by id and set `isSelect` field

```
onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex, e) => {
  setrowData((rows) => {
    return rows.map((r) => {
      if (r.id !== row.id) {
        return r;
      }

      return { ...r, isSelect };
    });
  });
},
```

4.`onSelectAll` set `isSelect` on all rows

```
onSelectAll: (isSelect, rows, e) => {
  setrowData((rows) => {
    return rows.map((row) => {
      return { ...row, isSelect };
    });
  });
}
```

5.for `Delete_device` just filter the data that is not selected :

```
  const Delete_device = () => {
    setrowData((rows) => {
      return rows.filter((row) => !row.isSelect);
    });
  };
```

6.for the delete button, get the selected rows and count them, if the count is > 0 then show the button :

```
const selectedRows = rowData.filter((row) => row.isSelect);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {selectedRows.length > 0 && (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={Delete_device}>
          <i className="ri-upload-cloud-line ri-lg"></i>Delete
        </button>
      )}
```

7.Pass the state data to BootstrapTable

```
  <BootstrapTable
    bootstrap4
    keyField="fname"
    data={rowData}
    columns={tableData[0].columnsData}
    selectRow={selectRow}
  />
```

[Complete example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-rgb-g2qm3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: No no for this I need to make a lot of changes, but still I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your state to use your data and removed the select array from your select logic. I also optimized it a bit. Its minor change from your codesandbox sample. Also, I recommend you use ids.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import "react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css";

let tableData = [
  {
    rowsData: [
      {
        fname: "john",
        lname: "smith"
      },
      {
        fname: "steve",
        lname: "warn"
      },
      {
        fname: "michel",
        lname: "clark"
      }
    ],
    columnsData: [
      {
        dataField: "fname",
        text: "First name",
        sort: true
      },
      {
        dataField: "lname",
        text: "last Name",
        sort: true
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [rowData, setrowData] = useState(tableData[0].rowsData);
  const [rowSelect, setrowSelect] = useState([]);

  const selectRow = useMemo(
    () => ({
      mode: "checkbox",
      clickToSelect: false,
      classes: "selection-row",
      onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex, e) => {
        setrowSelect((rowData) =>
          isSelect
            ? [...rowData, row]
            : rowData.filter(
                ({ fname, lname }) => row.fname !== fname && row.lname !== lname
              )
        );
        // if (isSelect === true) {
        //   setrowSelect((rowData) => [...rowData, row]);
        // } else {
        //   console.log("onSelect", rowIndex, row, isSelect);
        //   setrowSelect((rowData) =>
        //     rowData.filter(
        //       ({ fname, lname }) => row.fname !== fname && row.lname !== lname
        //     )
        //   );
        // }
      },

      onSelectAll: (isSelect, rows, e) => {
        if (isSelect === true) {
          setrowSelect(rows);
        } else setrowSelect([]);
      }
    }),
    []
  );
  const Delete_device = () => {
    console.log("Delete device", rowData, rowSelect);
    if (rowSelect.length < 1) return;
    setrowData((data) =>
      data.filter(
        ({ fname, lname }) =>
          rowSelect.find((s) => s.fname === fname && s.lname === lname) == null
      )
    );
    setrowSelect([]);
  };
  console.log("App", rowData, rowSelect);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {rowData.length > 0 && (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={Delete_device}>
          <i className="ri-upload-cloud-line ri-lg"></i>Delete
        </button>
      )}
      <BootstrapTable
        bootstrap4
        keyField="fname"
        data={rowData}
        columns={tableData[0].columnsData}
        selectRow={selectRow}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table-x-wus5r?file=/src/App.js